# Are MyLogins part of merging two my accounts?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, merge-accounts

I have two account here, these accounts are already in merging process

1st original [mKorbel (merge keep)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel?tab=summary) with OpenID login

2nd [mKorbel (merge delete)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853553/mkorbel) with Stack Exchange login

Is Stack Exchange login (from my 2nd. account) the subject of the merge, will I use Stack Exchange login as logon for my first account (after merging done)

Comment: It seems more logical to keep the log in method as the one you will be keeping, here meaning the OpenID login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is Stack Exchange login (from my 2nd. account) the subject of the
>   merge, will I use Stack Exchange login as logon for my first account
>   (after merging done)

- yes is possible, my account has two logins after merge,